# Mongoose trigger a post save hook on insertMany method

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am seeding the customers data to the mongodb database.
I want to save which generation group the customer belongs to, like Gen Z, Gen X, millenials, etc., in a separate collection based on the birth year. I am using the insertMany method to save the customer's information and not the create or save method.

and I don't intend to use the create or save method as well.

How can I trigger the post save middleware on the insertMany method? Any option I need to pass to trigger post save middleware on insertMany method?

```
CustomerSchema.post('save', async function (doc) {
    try {
        const year = doc.birthDate.getFullYear();
        console.log({ year });
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a post hook specifically for `insertMany`.
If you would like to run the same code also in `save` hook you can extract common logic into a function:

```
const postSaveHook = async (doc) => {
    try {
        const year = doc.birthDate.getFullYear();
        console.log({ year });
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
};

CustomerSchema.post('save', postSaveHook);

CustomerSchema.post('insertMany', async (docs, next) => {
    for (const doc of docs) {
        await postSaveHook(doc);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have tried the solution. It seems to be working but getting this error on the post insertMany middleware: ```Type 'Model<Customer, any, any, any, Document<unknown, any, Customer> & Omit<Customer & { _id: ObjectId; }, never>, any>' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.```

Comment: In my opinion if the solution works you can skip this Typescript error. Or maybe this issue would help https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/9755